# How can I determine the distribution of a statistic?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, likelihood-ratio

A similar question has been asked, but no answer was posted, so here I am again.
I was doing a Likelihood ratio test and it yielded an ugly expression. Take this example: if $X$ is $B(n,p)$ distributed, and the LRT $\Lambda(x)$ expression yielded the following expression $\prod x_{i}^{x_{i}}$, si in order to determine the critical value (we know that the critical rigion is $C=\{\Lambda(x)<c\}$), I have to find the distribution of the LRT statistic.
How can this be done?

hints and references are more than welcome.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here are two quick and dirty suggestions:

1. Boostrap the ugly espression and get an approximate numerical distribution. Use that to obtain your critical value.
2. Look into some functional approximation (like a Taylor expansion) of your ugly expression and try to work with that instead.

Look both of the above up on Google if you're not familiar.

Comment: Well, I did a monte carlo simulation, in addition to using the Distribution fitting app in Matlab, it seems that the distribution of my ugly expression is a GEV distribution, but I want to prove it analytically (if it's possible).